# Spark create a new string column based on max value of row_number and string value of another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose we have

```
id, hit, item, row_number
1234, 1, item1, 1
1234, 2, item2, 2
2345, 2, item1, 1
2345, 2, item2, 2
2345, 4, item3, 3
```

where `row_number` was created from windows function partitioned by `id` on `hit` in ascending order.

Now, I would like to create a new column `max_hit_item` which contains the name of the item with the highest `row_number` per user.

So in our example, it would return,

```
id, hit, item, row_number, max_hit_item
1234, 1, item1, 1, item2
1234, 2, item2, 2, item2
2345, 2, item1, 1, item3
2345, 2, item2, 2, item3
2345, 4, item3, 3, item3
```

I'm thinking since I do not want to drop any rows, I will have to use windows function. Is there a unique way of using windows function to achieve this? Ideally, I would like to not use join but any solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using window function `first`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(desc("hit"))
val result = df.withColumn("max_hit_item", first("item").over(w))
```